# How to deploy a custom PyTorch model into AWS and invoke it from EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have got a Python back end project that contains an AI model (model and utilities code as well as weights) for image processing (this model takes an input image, processes it then outputs the processed image) and REST APIs for user management and other miscellaneous tasks.

I am trying to deploy this project in AWS by splitting it. I'm aiming for deploying the REST API section of the project and the AI section separately, based on my research it would be more cost efficient. I'm going to deploy the API section of the project in an EC2 instance and I'm thinking to deploy the AI part of the project into SageMaker(or any other alternative).

But here is the thing I have an AI model and weights i don't want to train it or upload any code or files related to training (dataset, training code, etc.) in the AWS. I would like upload the model and invoke it from the EC2 instance whenever needed and acquire the processed image output.

What is the best approach to deploy a custom PyTorch model in AWS and which service is most suitable for my application?

How to invoke the model and get the output only when it is needed?

I've read some AWS documentation like "Deploy a Machine Learning Model to a Real-Time Inference Endpoint" and "Use PyTorch with Amazon SageMaker" and while the tutorials seems to be straight forward I wasn't able to implement it.

Thanks in advance for your help.